# Getting user credentials from Active Directory using LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have an application written using the Laravel framework in which I get details about the user directly from Active Directory.

The steps are as follows:

1. Hit the Intranet domain
2. The application determines a user's IP address with: `$user_ip = $request->ip();`
3. The user is redirected to a domain on a locally hosted server that houses the following script:

   ```
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <title>Newable Intranet</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div id="container">

   <?php 

       $login = $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
       $username = substr($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'], 6);  

       //LDAP Bind paramters, need to be a normal AD User account.
       $ldap_password = 'xxxxxx';
       $ldap_username = 'xxxxxx';
       $ldap_connection = ldap_connect("xxxxxx");

       if (FALSE === $ldap_connection)
       {
           // Uh-oh, something is wrong...
           echo 'Unable to connect to the ldap server';
       }
       else{
           // Do nothing
       }

       // We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
       ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
       ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

       if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password))
       {
           //Your domains DN to query
           $ldap_base_dn = 'OU=users,OU=company,DC=gleps,DC=local';

           //Get standard users and contacts
           $search_filter = '(|(objectCategory=user)(objectCategory=person))';

           //Connect to LDAP
           $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter);

           if (FALSE !== $result)
           {
               $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

               // Uncomment the below if you want to write all entries to debug somethingthing 
               // var_dump($entries);


               //For each account returned by the search
               for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++)
               {

                   //Windows Usernaame
                   $LDAP_samaccountname = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0])) 
                   {
                       $LDAP_samaccountname = $entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0];

                       if ($LDAP_samaccountname == "NULL")
                       {
                           $LDAP_samaccountname= "";
                       }
                   } 
                   else 
                   {
                       //#There is no samaccountname s0 assume this is an AD contact record so generate a unique username
                       $LDAP_uSNCreated = $entries[$x]['usncreated'][0];
                       $LDAP_samaccountname= "CONTACT_" . $LDAP_uSNCreated;
                   }

                   //Container Name
                   $LDAP_ContainerName = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['cn'][0])) 
                   {

                       $LDAP_ContainerName= $entries[$x]['cn'][0];

                       if ($LDAP_ContainerName == "NULL")
                       {
                           $LDAP_ContainerName = "";
                       }
                   }

                       //Department
                   $LDAP_Department = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['department'][0])) {
                       $LDAP_Department = $entries[$x]['department'][0];
                       if ($LDAP_Department == "NULL"){
                           $LDAP_Department = "";
                       }
                   }

                       //Location
                   $LDAP_Office = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['physicaldeliveryofficename'][0])) {
                       $LDAP_Office = $entries[$x]['physicaldeliveryofficename'][0];   
                       if ($LDAP_Office == "NULL"){
                           $LDAP_Office = "";
                       }
                   }

                           //Display Name
                   $LDAP_Display = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['displayname'][0])) 
                   {
                       $LDAP_Display = $entries[$x]['displayname'][0];

                       if ($LDAP_Display == "NULL")
                       {
                           $LDAP_Display = "";
                       }
                   }


                   $LDAP_JobTitle = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['title'][0])) {
                       $LDAP_JobTitle = $entries[$x]['title'][0];
                       if ($LDAP_JobTitle == "NULL"){
                           $LDAP_JobTitle = "";
                       }
                   }

                   $LDAP_MngUN = "";

                           if (!empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0])) 
                           {
                               $LDAP_MngUN = $entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0];

                               if ($LDAP_MngUN == "NULL")
                               {
                                   $LDAP_MngUN= "";
                               }
                           } 
                           else 
                           {
                               //#There is no samaccountname s0 assume this is an AD contact record so generate a unique username
                               $LDAP_uSNCreated = $entries[$x]['usncreated'][0];
                               $LDAP_MngUN = "CONTACT_" . $LDAP_uSNCreated;
                           }

                           //Last Name
                           $LDAP_MngCN = "";


                           if (!empty($entries[$x]['cn'][0])) 
                           {
                               $LDAP_MngCN = $entries[$x]['cn'][0];

                               if ($LDAP_MngCN == "NULL"){
                                   $LDAP_MngCN = "";
                               }
                           }

                   //Email address
                   $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0])) {
                       $LDAP_InternetAddress = $entries[$x]['mail'][0];    
                       if ($LDAP_InternetAddress == "NULL"){
                           $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";
                       }
                   }

                       //Telephone Number
                   $LDAP_DDI = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['telephonenumber'][0])) {
                       $LDAP_DDI = $entries[$x]['telephonenumber'][0];
                       if ($LDAP_DDI == "NULL"){
                           $LDAP_DDI = "";
                       }
                   }
                   //Mobile Number
                   $LDAP_CellPhone = "";

                   if (!empty($entries[$x]['mobile'][0])) {
                       $LDAP_CellPhone = $entries[$x]['mobile'][0];
                       if ($LDAP_CellPhone == "NULL"){
                           $LDAP_CellPhone = "";
                       }
                   }



                   if ($LDAP_samaccountname == $username)  
                   {



                       ?>

                       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                       <script type="text/javascript">


                           var UN = "<?php echo $LDAP_samaccountname ?>";
                           var CN = "<?php echo $LDAP_ContainerName ?>";
                           var DN = "<?php echo $LDAP_Display ?>";
                           var JT = "<?php echo $LDAP_JobTitle ?>";
                           var DP = "<?php echo $LDAP_Department ?>";
                           var OF = "<?php echo $LDAP_Office ?>";
                           var EM = "<?php echo $LDAP_InternetAddress ?>";
                           var DD = "<?php echo $LDAP_DDI ?>";
                           var MO = "<?php echo $LDAP_CellPhone ?>";
                           var MUN = "<?php echo $LDAP_MngUN ?>";
                           var MCN = "<?php echo $LDAP_MngCN ?>";


                           var form = $(document.createElement('form'));

                           $(form).attr("action", "https://mynewable.co.uk/");
                           $(form).attr("method", "POST");
                           $(form).css("display", "none");

                           var input_User_name = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "UN")
                           .val(UN);

                           $(form).append($(input_User_name));

                            var input_Container_name = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "CN")
                           .val(CN);
                           $(form).append($(input_Container_name));


                            var input_Display_name = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "DN")
                           .val(DN);
                           $(form).append($(input_Display_name));

                            var input_Job_title = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "JT")
                           .val(JT);
                           $(form).append($(input_Job_title));

                           var input_Department = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "DP")
                           .val(DP);
                           $(form).append($(input_Department));

                           var input_Department = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "DP")
                           .val(DP);
                           $(form).append($(input_Department));

                           var input_Office = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "OF")
                           .val(OF);
                           $(form).append($(input_Office));

                           var input_Email = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "EM")
                           .val(EM);
                           $(form).append($(input_Email));

                           var input_DDI = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "DD")
                           .val(DD);
                           $(form).append($(input_DDI));

                           var input_Mobile = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "MO")
                           .val(MO);
                           $(form).append($(input_Mobile));

                           var input_Manager_Uname = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "MUN")
                           .val(MUN);
                           $(form).append($(input_Manager_Uname));

                           var input_Manager_Cname = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "MCN")
                           .val(MCN);
                           $(form).append($(input_Manager_Cname));

                            var Tholia = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "Tholia")
                           .val("TRUE");
                           $(form).append($(Tholia));

                           var input_conf = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "text")
                           .attr("name", "confirmation")
                           .val("1");

                           $(form).append($(input_conf));

                           var sub = $("<input>")
                           .attr("type", "submit")
                           .val("submit");

                           $(form).append($(sub));



                           form.appendTo( document.body );

                           $(form).submit();

                       </script>   

                   <?php       
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ?>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

The reason I am going with this approach is because I cannot directly connect to AD from the web server, however POSTing across the user details feels like I'm opening myself up to security vulnerabilities.

Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: What is the point of this script ? Do you need to sync user data from AD to your website ? *"I cannot directly connect to AD from the web server"* well you are actually binding to it and doing all the stuff using php... And why would you pass these data clientside to only have to POST them ? why not using curl ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing what you're doing, but as long as you're POSTing via HTTPS, then I don't see anything insecure about it.

Comment: I agree with you both, but I need to be able to redirect and send the data. If I used CURL could I also redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an appropriate specification that is suitable for the use-case you describe; like OpenID Connect.